# Spring restdocs conditionally highlight optional parameters with asciidoc

Tags: java, maven, rest-assured, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I am using spring restdocs to produce documentation on my REST webapi; I have integrated the thing and my html gets generated (maven + asciidoc plugin, restassured apis).
The only problem I have is that ifeval either doesn't work as advertised or I got it wrong.

My custom request-fields.snippet looks like this:

```
|===
|Path|Type|Description|Optional

{{#fields}}
 |{{#tableCellContent}}
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `{{path}}`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"="false"]
   *`{{path}}`*
endif::[]
  {{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}`{{type}}`{{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}{{description}}{{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}{{optional}}{{/tableCellContent}}

{{/fields}}
|===
```

The 'optional' value in the tablecellcontent is rendered correctly ('true' or 'false' depending on the case), but the ifeval is not parsed (and thus shows itself unparsed on the final html, with no error).

I tried different syntaxes for the expression but none seem to work; any hints on what may be the correct syntax, if any?
I am thinking about defining a custom attribute and use ifndef to get the same result, but I would prefer to use the existing optional() support if possible.

As requested I am adding the resulting .adoc

```
|===
|Path|Type|Description|Optional

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `name`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`name`*
endif::[]
|`String`
|Name of the new Axis
|false

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `description`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`description`*
endif::[]
|`String`
|Description of the new Axis
|true

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `tags[]`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`tags[]`*
endif::[]
|`TagDto[]`
|Hierarchical view of axis' tags
|false

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `tags[].id`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`tags[].id`*
endif::[]
|`Number`
|Id of the tag
|false

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `tags[].name`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`tags[].name`*
endif::[]
|`String`
|Name of the tag
|false

|
ifeval::["{optional}"=="true"]
   `tags[].children`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{optional}"=="false"]
   *`tags[].children`*
endif::[]
|`TagDto[]`
|Child tags for this tag, if any
|true

|===
```

Comment: I just learned that directives must be at the beginning of the line; but even correcting that I still don't get the right result (all lines have the same formatting, disregarding optional value)

Comment: One mistake you have in the above is `=` rather than `==` in the second condition but that could just be a typo in the question. Rather than looking at the custom template, can you share the generated `.adoc` snippet? Also, how have you included the snippet in your main `.adoc` file?

Comment: Yes it is included, and the = was a typo; I added the generated adoc. 
This in particular results in no value printed for "path"
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your custom template where you're using `{optional}` rather than `{{optional}}` in the `ifeval` macros. This means that `{optional}` isn't being replaced with the field's `optional` attribute and, as a result, Asciidoctor is evaluating either `"{optional}"=="true"` or `"{optional}"=="false"`.

You need to update your template to use `{{optional}}`:

```
|===
|Path|Type|Description|Optional

{{#fields}}
 |{{#tableCellContent}}
ifeval::["{{optional}}"=="true"]
   `{{path}}`
endif::[]
ifeval::["{{optional}}"=="false"]
   *`{{path}}`*
endif::[]
  {{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}`{{type}}`{{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}{{description}}{{/tableCellContent}}
  |{{#tableCellContent}}{{optional}}{{/tableCellContent}}

{{/fields}}
|===
```

Comment: thanks, I was sure I tried this before and it didn't work; this morning it did. Probably there was something else wrong before...

Comment: There is error in the second if. Should be `ifeval::["{{optional}}"=="false"]`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.